# VS2015 requires more references than previous versions?

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2015

We recently installed the RTM of Visual Studio 2015 and immediately noticed a weird problem with our solutions. Most (if not all) of our solutions fail to build because we are 'missing' references (which we did not need in Visual Studio 2013!).

Our previous references have not suddenly stopped working or disappeared in the solution, we just need more references than we did before. The reference errors are mostly to our own framework but also to external dlls like Infragistics.

[image: FwkReferenceErrors]
[image: InfragisticsErrors]

If we add these extra references everything works fine, but there must be a reason for this? We cannot find any documentation for this behavior and are quite flabbergasted.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and/or is there a logical explanation for this?

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

While I admit I haven't used Infragistics in a long while, I remember it having an installer, asking you to specify which Visual Studio versions to install itself into.

The way Visual Studio works, is that all components must be installed into Visual Studio, otherwise it will be unable to find them, which is what I suspect happens here -- your Visual Studio 2015 has no idea about Infragistics, this is why it can't "find" all those assembly references.

Simply reinstall Infragistics, make sure to select **Visual Studio 2015** somewhere during the installation. You might need a newer version of Infragistics for this, I suggest checking their website.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, but our problem isn't that Visual Studio 2015 can't find our references (we reference the .dll files directly), it's that it seems to need *more* references. References which we have never needed before!

Comment: @Thomas The major change in Visual Studio 2015 is that the compiler (Roslyn) was rewritten from scratch, and it might behave differently than the previous versions (with regards to how references are resolved) - see [this link](http://blog.slaks.net/2014-05-28/exploring-roslyn-part-3-breaking-changes/#loading-indirectly-referenced-assemblies-during-compilation) for example. This could also explain it...

Comment: It might, but that's not really explained very well. Other people must have the same problem? I think I'll keep looking but thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

VS 2015 needs a reference to resolve all the types even if you don't use them. For example, the types of the parameters in unused method overloads.

Comment: add this in comment this is not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10565361)

Comment: @LucaDetomi: Being short, this is actually an answer: it reveals (or answerer think so) the actual reason of the problem in the question post. If you find this answer being not useful, just downvote it. In that case think also about adding comment, describing the reason.